# Does my parameter value store its value i.e. memory - if button clicked divert macro to second macro

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code of two sub procedures, one function, two other sub procedures for macro protection (irrelevant). The last sub procedure, `sub manual_date()` is the center of my inquiry. How could I divert the macro code if the user of this macro choose to manually input their own date. The main code is highlighted as the center code screen. I know I could very easily copy and paste as a solution. I am interested in an advanced coding strategy.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Client_Dirty_Recon()

Dim Date_minus_one As Date              ' Date & weekend logic
Dim answer As Long                      ' Date & weekend logic
Dim brow As Long                        ' Last filled cell in column
Dim yrow As Long                        ' Last filled cell in column
Dim nRow As Long                        ' Last filled cell in column
Dim c As Range                          ' rngWatch.Cells(i, 1).Value
Dim oldStatusBar As Variant             ' Save StatusBar status
Dim Client_path As String               ' Range("Path")
Dim wb As Workbook                      ' ThisWorkbook
Dim wbDirty As Workbook                 ' Workbooks.Open(Client_path)
Dim rngReconcile As Range               ' wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
Dim rngWatch As Range                   ' wbDirty.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
Dim rngNew As Range                     ' wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
Dim failed_count As Long
Dim FS


oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar     'optional - save StatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True             'optional - turn on StatusBar
Application.ScreenUpdating = False              'optional - screen won't flash
Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbooks..."  'optional - Update user

Call Unprot

Date_minus_one = Date
answer = IsMonday(Date_minus_one)

If answer = True Then
Date_minus_one = Date - 3
    Else
    Date_minus_one = Date - 1
End If

Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
' Client_path = wb.Names("Path").RefersToRange.Value    ' use path as defined name on sheet
Client_path = "XXXXXXX " & Format(Date_minus_one, "mmddyyyy") & ".xls"


If FS.fileexists(Client_path) Then

' Get only used part of column
Set rngReconcile = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")
nRow = rngReconcile(rngReconcile.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ' Get last filled cell
Set rngReconcile = Range(rngReconcile(1), rngReconcile(nRow)) ' Reduce rng size

Set wbDirty = Workbooks.Open(Client_path)   ' Assumes it exists and is not open
' Get only used part of column
Set rngWatch = wbDirty.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
nRow = rngWatch(rngWatch.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row     ' Get last filled cell
Set rngWatch = Range(rngWatch(3), rngWatch(nRow))       ' Reduce range size

Set rngNew = wb.Sheets("Client Watchlist").Range("K:K")
brow = rngNew(rngNew.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngNew = Range(rngNew(2), rngNew(brow))
rngNew.ClearContents

Set rngNew = wb.Sheets(1).Range("K:K")(rngNew.Cells.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

For Each c In rngWatch                   ' Each value in rngWatch
    On Error Resume Next                 ' Interrupt Error checking
    If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match( _
        c.Value, rngReconcile, 0)) Then  ' If not in rngReconcile
        rngNew.FormulaR1C1 = c.Value     ' Copy to rngNew
        Set rngNew = rngNew(2)           ' Moves range down =Offset(rngNew,1,0)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0                      ' Reset Error checking
    If (c.Row + 1) Mod 100 = 0 Then      ' Optional - Update user
        Application.StatusBar = "Evaluating cell " & c(2).Address & "..."
    End If
Next c

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar ' Reset Status Bar
ActiveWindow.Close Savechanges:=False       ' Closes client email


MsgBox ("Reconcilied to ") & Client_path & " on " & Now

Else

MsgBox ("Please save down ") & Client_path, vbCritical

End If


Call Prot

Application.ScreenUpdating = True           ' Turn back on

End Sub


Public Function IsMonday(inputdate As Date) As Boolean
    Select Case Weekday(inputdate)
        Case vbMonday
            IsMonday = True
        Case Else
            IsMonday = False
    End Select
End Function

Sub manual_date()
manual_date_input = InputBox("Enter Date (MMDDYYYY")


End Sub
```

#### Update

I added the following two sub procedures which shall pass the `dt` parameter as instructed below. I feel as if this variable `dt as date` is storing a value? I am able to run the sub procedure `Sub RunWithUserDate()` but the `Sub RunWithDefault()` procedure does not run smoothly. I have inserted several message boxes to view the value of `dt`. Should I be resetting the value of this date variable? If so, how could I? (Please note, I have cleaned up the code within the main sub procedure `Sub Client_Dirty_Recon()` and I have properly assigned the `dt` variable within the `client_path` variable.

```
Sub test2()
MsgBox Date

MsgBox dt

MsgBox IsMonday(dt)
IsMonday (dt)

MsgBox (dt)

End Sub
Public Function IsMonday(inputdate As Date) As Boolean
    
    Select Case Weekday(inputdate)
        Case vbMonday
            dt = Date - 3               ' IsMonday = True
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
        Case Else
            dt = Date - 1
            'dt = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyyyy")           ' IsMonday = False
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
    End Select
    
End Function

Sub RunWithDefault()                    ' Button 1: use current date
'CHECK THIS AGAIN ***ALSO ADD PERMISSIONS IF NECESSARY
    MsgBox IsMonday(dt)
    MsgBox dt
    
    Client_Dirty_Recon IsMonday(dt)
    

End Sub
                                        ' Button 2: get date from user
Sub RunWithUserDate()                   ' Get dt value from user
'PROMPT USER FOR PASSWORD

    dt = Application.InputBox("Enter Date (MM/DD/YYYY)", "Manual Override")
    'du = Format(du, "mmddyyyy")
    
    'du = Format(Application.InputBox("Enter Date (MM/DD/YYYY)"), "mmddyyyy")

    'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
'MsgBox dt
        Client_Dirty_Recon dt
     'dt = Date
     
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you mean by divert? Do you mean to call other macro in manual_date subroutine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Date parameter to your main sub, and have (e.g.) two separate buttons, each linked to smaller "stubs" which in turn will call the main code. First one would pass the current date; second one would pass a date sourced from the user somehow.

```
'button 1: use current date
Sub RunWithDefault()
    Client_Dirty_Recon Date
End Sub

'button 2: get date from user
Sub RunWithUserDate()
    Dim dt As Date
    'get dt value from user
    Client_Dirty_Recon dt
End Sub


'main code
Sub Client_Dirty_Recon(dt as Date)
    'run main processing
End Sub
```